# Normalise.css along with burbon bitters

Tags: sass, normalize, bourbon

It seems that bitters by `Bourbon Sass` library sets up the base for a project. Do you need to use `normalise.css` along with bitters or bitters does the same work?

It seems to me that the use of `normalise.css` is a bit redundant.

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Bitters's Github page, they recommends Normalize as a CSS reset.

> Bitters is made to work alongside a CSS reset and not replace it. Our suggested reset is Normalize.

Source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters

Regards.